# Excel search and return

Tags: excel

So, I have an Excel-file with two sheets. The first sheet contains 7 Columns of different values.
The second sheet contains a list of special customer prices.

What i want to do, is basicly search for the value given in e.g. cell A2, in Sheet2!A:A. If i were to find this value (it's a text value), I want to return the value located in that spesific row containing the value searched for, only 3 colums to the right.

I've done a lot of experiments, but really can't get INDEX and MATCH to do the work properly for me. Anyh suggestions?

Feel free to ask for more information, as I know I can be a challange to understand..

Best regards

Comment: Show what you have tried, and in what way(s) it fell short.

Comment: First of all, I'm a rookie in excel, but thi is what I've tried:
=IF(Priser!A11=MATCH(Priser!A11;Spesialpriser!A:A;0);INDEX(MATCH(Priser!A11;Spesialpriser!A:A;0);;3))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try offset() and match(), offset(reference,rows,cols). use match to find the number of rows or columns to move from the reference point.

Comment: So, I tried working with offset and match.
This is what I figured it had to be:
=IF(MATCH(A11;Spesialpriser!A:A;0);OFFSET(MATCH(A11;Spesialpriser!A:a;0);0;2);(D11-(D11*E11)))

The problem is, it doesnt return any value, at all. An error pops up, and I can't seem to figure out why!

Comment: What is the reference for your offset function? it goes straight into match(), if the target you are looking for is in column A and the data starts in A1 then use A1 : OFFSET(A1;MATCH(A11 and so on. Also, try it without the IF() function first.

Comment: Thanks alot, I did that to test it.
I've edited it, and now got the formula:
=IF(MATCH(A11;Spesialpriser!A:A;0);OFFSET(Spesialpriser!A6;0;2))
Everything works perfectly, with one exception:
No matter where in A:A the value is found, it returns the offset value from cell "Spesialpriser!A6". I know why, my formula says it should.
Question is, how can I return the value 2 colums from the matched value? Like, when I find the value, return the value 2 colums next to it?
Hope you understand what I mean

Comment: OFFSET(ref; rows; cols) add the 3rd argument so if it is always 2 columns just put 2. In your example the match is used to control the IF(), so when true the offset moves 2 columns right and no rows,  what about : OFFSET(Spesialpriser!A6;MATCH(A11;Spesialpriser!A:A;0);2))   but not sure if that does what you want but it does show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Using OFFSET is against almost all best practice guides. It is a volatile function, meaning it should be avoided at all costs. Use INDEX+MATCH instead. It can do all the same stuff but has much better performance.

```
=INDEX(column holding the value you want to return, match to find row #, 1)
=MATCH(value you are looking for, column you are searching in, 0 means exact match)
```

Result:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$10,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10,0),1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I will test index and match.

Comment: Thanks alot, I will defenitly give this one a go!

Comment: I get what you mean, but it doesnt do quite what I imagined. This will return the value searched for, just lika  VLOOKUP, right? What I do got now, is:

=IF(MATCH(A11;Sheet2!A:A;0);INDEX(MATCH(A11;Sheet2!A:A;0);2);2)

So, I want to search for the value of A11 in sheet1, in the range A:A in sheet2. If I find a match, I want to return the value located 2 colums to the right of where this match is found. If not, return the value 2.
This does'nt seem tok be working in the above formula..

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,MATCH($A$11,Sheet2!$A:$A,0),1),2)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the function you are looking for is a vlookup.  Try this:

=vlookup(A2, Sheet2!A:D, 4, 0)

Regards,
Windyvation

Comment: So, I implemented VLOOKUP, and it worked! Or at least, my logical test did. Now, I'm having some issues with the OFFSET part of the formula.
The formula looks like this at the moment:

=IF(VLOOKUP(A6;Sheet2!A1:A100;1)=A6;OFFSET(Sheet2!A1;MATCH(Sheet1!A6;Sheet2!A1:A100;0);2);(D6-(D6*E6)))

It wokrs out perfectly at first glance, but, after a closer look, it returns the value of the cell right beneeth. Any idea why?

Comment: I believe this is related to the offset function, which I haven't used so you're troubleshooting would be as good as mine: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US